# Wordpress Image Size

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm creating a team page that needs to include many team members' profile images, due to the image quality and sizes being different, I tried to modify it in the HTML code by simply setting them to the same width and length. However, in the preview, the width seems to match but the length is still different. Is it because the images are set to be must in proportion to the original image? Is there any way I could tackle this and make them all in one standard size?

Comment: i suppose you are newbie so i think it will help to solve your problem https://enginescout.com.au/wordpress-image-sizes/

Comment: @RobinHood Thank you!! Yea... I was put on the spot because I know some other coding languages, sooo still a lot need to be learned haha

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simple w ay if you be uploading images, just add custom image size like

```
add_image_size( 'team', 390, 490, array( 'top', 'center' ));
```

But if client is uplading images :D :D, then expect images be to small for croping them to thumbnails. then easies  way to do this, have figure with backtround image, set to top center / contain no-repeat, and in figure just have transparent png image with right ratio

```
<figure style="background: url(IMAGE_SRC) top center / contain no-repeat;"><img src="TRANSPARENT.PNG"></figure>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! So, do I just need to add the **add_image_size** command where I set up my images?